# Why are NSString characters specified with %c being altered?

Tags: ios, utf-8, character-encoding, nsstring

I was trying to test some code involving conversion between string encodings and discovered this phenomenon when trying to create an NSString with an invalid UTF-8 sequence:

```
char before = 0xa1;
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",before];
char after = [s characterAtIndex:0]; // = 0xb0
```

For most (but not all) characters in the 0x80-0xFF range, the character in the NSString is not the same one I specified.

Does anybody have any idea why this?

Here are the before and after values for all possible char values:

> 1 -> 1
>
> 2 -> 2
>
> 3 -> 3
>
> 4 -> 4
>
> 5 -> 5
>
> 6 -> 6
>
> 7 -> 7
>
> 8 -> 8
>
> 9 -> 9
>
> a -> a
>
> b -> b
>
> c -> c
>
> d -> d
>
> e -> e
>
> f -> f
>
> 10 -> 10
>
> 11 -> 11
>
> 12 -> 12
>
> 13 -> 13
>
> 14 -> 14
>
> 15 -> 15
>
> 16 -> 16
>
> 17 -> 17
>
> 18 -> 18
>
> 19 -> 19
>
> 1a -> 1a
>
> 1b -> 1b
>
> 1c -> 1c
>
> 1d -> 1d
>
> 1e -> 1e
>
> 1f -> 1f
>
> 20 -> 20
>
> 21 -> 21
>
> 22 -> 22
>
> 23 -> 23
>
> 24 -> 24
>
> 25 -> 25
>
> 26 -> 26
>
> 27 -> 27
>
> 28 -> 28
>
> 29 -> 29
>
> 2a -> 2a
>
> 2b -> 2b
>
> 2c -> 2c
>
> 2d -> 2d
>
> 2e -> 2e
>
> 2f -> 2f
>
> 30 -> 30
>
> 31 -> 31
>
> 32 -> 32
>
> 33 -> 33
>
> 34 -> 34
>
> 35 -> 35
>
> 36 -> 36
>
> 37 -> 37
>
> 38 -> 38
>
> 39 -> 39
>
> 3a -> 3a
>
> 3b -> 3b
>
> 3c -> 3c
>
> 3d -> 3d
>
> 3e -> 3e
>
> 3f -> 3f
>
> 40 -> 40
>
> 41 -> 41
>
> 42 -> 42
>
> 43 -> 43
>
> 44 -> 44
>
> 45 -> 45
>
> 46 -> 46
>
> 47 -> 47
>
> 48 -> 48
>
> 49 -> 49
>
> 4a -> 4a
>
> 4b -> 4b
>
> 4c -> 4c
>
> 4d -> 4d
>
> 4e -> 4e
>
> 4f -> 4f
>
> 50 -> 50
>
> 51 -> 51
>
> 52 -> 52
>
> 53 -> 53
>
> 54 -> 54
>
> 55 -> 55
>
> 56 -> 56
>
> 57 -> 57
>
> 58 -> 58
>
> 59 -> 59
>
> 5a -> 5a
>
> 5b -> 5b
>
> 5c -> 5c
>
> 5d -> 5d
>
> 5e -> 5e
>
> 5f -> 5f
>
> 60 -> 60
>
> 61 -> 61
>
> 62 -> 62
>
> 63 -> 63
>
> 64 -> 64
>
> 65 -> 65
>
> 66 -> 66
>
> 67 -> 67
>
> 68 -> 68
>
> 69 -> 69
>
> 6a -> 6a
>
> 6b -> 6b
>
> 6c -> 6c
>
> 6d -> 6d
>
> 6e -> 6e
>
> 6f -> 6f
>
> 70 -> 70
>
> 71 -> 71
>
> 72 -> 72
>
> 73 -> 73
>
> 74 -> 74
>
> 75 -> 75
>
> 76 -> 76
>
> 77 -> 77
>
> 78 -> 78
>
> 79 -> 79
>
> 7a -> 7a
>
> 7b -> 7b
>
> 7c -> 7c
>
> 7d -> 7d
>
> 7e -> 7e
>
> 7f -> 7f
>
> 80 -> c4 [CHANGED]
>
> 81 -> c5 [CHANGED]
>
> 82 -> c7 [CHANGED]
>
> 83 -> c9 [CHANGED]
>
> 84 -> d1 [CHANGED]
>
> 85 -> d6 [CHANGED]
>
> 86 -> dc [CHANGED]
>
> 87 -> e1 [CHANGED]
>
> 88 -> e0 [CHANGED]
>
> 89 -> e2 [CHANGED]
>
> 8a -> e4 [CHANGED]
>
> 8b -> e3 [CHANGED]
>
> 8c -> e5 [CHANGED]
>
> 8d -> e7 [CHANGED]
>
> 8e -> e9 [CHANGED]
>
> 8f -> e8 [CHANGED]
>
> 90 -> ea [CHANGED]
>
> 91 -> eb [CHANGED]
>
> 92 -> ed [CHANGED]
>
> 93 -> ec [CHANGED]
>
> 94 -> ee [CHANGED]
>
> 95 -> ef [CHANGED]
>
> 96 -> f1 [CHANGED]
>
> 97 -> f3 [CHANGED]
>
> 98 -> f2 [CHANGED]
>
> 99 -> f4 [CHANGED]
>
> 9a -> f6 [CHANGED]
>
> 9b -> f5 [CHANGED]
>
> 9c -> fa [CHANGED]
>
> 9d -> f9 [CHANGED]
>
> 9e -> fb [CHANGED]
>
> 9f -> fc [CHANGED]
>
> a0 -> 2020 [CHANGED]
>
> a1 -> b0 [CHANGED]
>
> a2 -> a2
>
> a3 -> a3
>
> a4 -> a7 [CHANGED]
>
> a5 -> 2022 [CHANGED]
>
> a6 -> b6 [CHANGED]
>
> a7 -> df [CHANGED]
>
> a8 -> ae [CHANGED]
>
> a9 -> a9
>
> aa -> 2122 [CHANGED]
>
> ab -> b4 [CHANGED]
>
> ac -> a8 [CHANGED]
>
> ad -> 2260 [CHANGED]
>
> ae -> c6 [CHANGED]
>
> af -> d8 [CHANGED]
>
> b0 -> 221e [CHANGED]
>
> b1 -> b1
>
> b2 -> 2264 [CHANGED]
>
> b3 -> 2265 [CHANGED]
>
> b4 -> a5 [CHANGED]
>
> b5 -> b5
>
> b6 -> 2202 [CHANGED]
>
> b7 -> 2211 [CHANGED]
>
> b8 -> 220f [CHANGED]
>
> b9 -> 3c0 [CHANGED]
>
> ba -> 222b [CHANGED]
>
> bb -> aa [CHANGED]
>
> bc -> ba [CHANGED]
>
> bd -> 3a9 [CHANGED]
>
> be -> e6 [CHANGED]
>
> bf -> f8 [CHANGED]
>
> c0 -> bf [CHANGED]
>
> c1 -> a1 [CHANGED]
>
> c2 -> ac [CHANGED]
>
> c3 -> 221a [CHANGED]
>
> c4 -> 192 [CHANGED]
>
> c5 -> 2248 [CHANGED]
>
> c6 -> 2206 [CHANGED]
>
> c7 -> ab [CHANGED]
>
> c8 -> bb [CHANGED]
>
> c9 -> 2026 [CHANGED]
>
> ca -> a0 [CHANGED]
>
> cb -> c0 [CHANGED]
>
> cc -> c3 [CHANGED]
>
> cd -> d5 [CHANGED]
>
> ce -> 152 [CHANGED]
>
> cf -> 153 [CHANGED]
>
> d0 -> 2013 [CHANGED]
>
> d1 -> 2014 [CHANGED]
>
> d2 -> 201c [CHANGED]
>
> d3 -> 201d [CHANGED]
>
> d4 -> 2018 [CHANGED]
>
> d5 -> 2019 [CHANGED]
>
> d6 -> f7 [CHANGED]
>
> d7 -> 25ca [CHANGED]
>
> d8 -> ff [CHANGED]
>
> d9 -> 178 [CHANGED]
>
> da -> 2044 [CHANGED]
>
> db -> 20ac [CHANGED]
>
> dc -> 2039 [CHANGED]
>
> dd -> 203a [CHANGED]
>
> de -> fb01 [CHANGED]
>
> df -> fb02 [CHANGED]
>
> e0 -> 2021 [CHANGED]
>
> e1 -> b7 [CHANGED]
>
> e2 -> 201a [CHANGED]
>
> e3 -> 201e [CHANGED]
>
> e4 -> 2030 [CHANGED]
>
> e5 -> c2 [CHANGED]
>
> e6 -> ca [CHANGED]
>
> e7 -> c1 [CHANGED]
>
> e8 -> cb [CHANGED]
>
> e9 -> c8 [CHANGED]
>
> ea -> cd [CHANGED]
>
> eb -> ce [CHANGED]
>
> ec -> cf [CHANGED]
>
> ed -> cc [CHANGED]
>
> ee -> d3 [CHANGED]
>
> ef -> d4 [CHANGED]
>
> f0 -> f8ff [CHANGED]
>
> f1 -> d2 [CHANGED]
>
> f2 -> da [CHANGED]
>
> f3 -> db [CHANGED]
>
> f4 -> d9 [CHANGED]
>
> f5 -> 131 [CHANGED]
>
> f6 -> 2c6 [CHANGED]
>
> f7 -> 2dc [CHANGED]
>
> f8 -> af [CHANGED]
>
> f9 -> 2d8 [CHANGED]
>
> fa -> 2d9 [CHANGED]
>
> fb -> 2da [CHANGED]
>
> fc -> b8 [CHANGED]
>
> fd -> 2dd [CHANGED]
>
> fe -> 2db [CHANGED]
>
> ff -> 2c7 [CHANGED]

Comment: Well, UTF-8 needs at least two bytes for any codepoint >= 0x80, so maybe this is unspecified behavior?

Comment: Yeah, I assume this is unspecified behavior, but I'm still trying to find the reasoning behind not simply returning null and understand what might be happening under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
unichar before = 0xa1;
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",before];

unichar after = [s characterAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Read back char was %C", after);
```

Technically a "char" tpe should be 0-127. UTF8 uses the two higher bits, so its somewhat undefined what a single "0xFF" would generate. When you use stringWithFormat, chars are promoted to ints, so your 0xA0 gets turned into 0xFFFFFFA0, and the system may look for a negative value and do who knows what.